# SQL - item that appears in all buckets in Certain Category

Tags: sql, select, count, distinct

I have this table(table name CH);

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ ID_A ║ ID_B ║Category_A║Category_B║
╠══════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║   1  ║   1  ║    1     ║     5    ║
║   1  ║   2  ║    1     ║     5    ║
║   1  ║   3  ║    1     ║     5    ║
║   1  ║   1  ║    2     ║     5    ║
║   1  ║   3  ║    2     ║     5    ║
║   1  ║   1  ║    3     ║     5    ║
║   1  ║   2  ║    3     ║     5    ║
║   2  ║   1  ║    1     ║     4    ║
║   2  ║   2  ║    1     ║     3    ║
║   2  ║   2  ║    2     ║     2    ║
║   2  ║   2  ║    3     ║     1    ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

ID_A = 1 & ID_B = 1 appears all in the Category_A(=1,2,3)
and also
ID_A = 2 & ID_B = 2 appears all in the Category_A(=1,2,3)

Are there anyway to select those kinds of rows?
I've tried select distinct or count distinct with condition but failed.

```
select * from ch group by ID_A, ID_B having count(ditinct Category_A)=4;
```

I expect table like this;

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ ID_A ║ ID_B ║Category_A║Category_B║
╠══════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║   1  ║   1  ║    1     ║     5    ║
║   1  ║   1  ║    2     ║     5    ║
║   1  ║   1  ║    3     ║     5    ║
║   2  ║   2  ║    1     ║     3    ║
║   2  ║   2  ║    2     ║     2    ║
║   2  ║   2  ║    3     ║     1    ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Seems you want  *Relational Division*, IDs which exist in every category

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks I did not know that concept. I should have known! Thanks for defining my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT ID_A, ID_B, COUNT(DISTINCT Category_A) as COUNT_CAT_A
  FROM CH
  GROUP BY ID_A, ID_B 
) X
WHERE COUNT_CAT_A = 3
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! It works!!!! How can I thank you? I voted but it does not seem applied...

Comment: @wookidoki  You might have to wait a while till you can since you are new at some point you should be able to select this as the answer you want and click the up arrow to up vote.